# The music listened by Google Play Music on my Samsung J5 cannot be controlled by my Garmin Forerunner 55 connected watch

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-j5

I have a *Samsung J5* smartphone with *Garmin Connect* and *Connect IQ* applications, both linked to my watch: a *Garmin Forerunner 55*.

I can synchronize my activities with *Garmin Connect* without trouble.

However, the control music function, that is supposed to handle the music listened on my smartphone, doesn't detect anything being listened, when I use the *Google Play Music* application (the only one that is installed in my phone).

Have I missed an installation step?

Comment: "Have I missed an installation step?" No. When you play music on the phone its notification will be shown on the watch. Go to notifications and open the music controls from there https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=AtUlAYSfU-0